# Delete row from DB table using cron job

Tags: mysql, cron

I'm wondering how can I delete a row from given database table using cron job, can I do that directly using the cron job command line in my cPanel?
I'm using MySQL Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MySQL's [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/events.html):

```
CREATE EVENT foo ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 3 HOUR
DO DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = 123
```